# CoreData: How to sort NSManagedObject by its primary key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have one subclass of NSManagedObject like following 
and stored some instances by NSManagedObjectContext.

```
@interface SomeModelObject : NSManagedObject  
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text; 
@end
```

Now, I want to fetch the list sorted by its primary key (created automatically).
I've tried NSFetchRequest and got runtime error: "keypath id not found in entity".

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeModelObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sort, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Is it possible to sort by primary key? Or should I add some column to Model class for sorting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that the primary key is an opaque data type whose value is an arbitrary implementation detail completely outside of your control (including potentially not being constant over time), it seems non-sensical to want to sort by it.

If you are looking for a stable, determined, order, then -- yes -- sort by a different attribute, either an existing one or a new one.

Note that, in general, it is best to not think of Core Data in relational database terms.  Focus on the object graph and object modeling aspects as that is what the APIs are focused upon.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will add some column for sorting.

Yes, I understand Core Data treat object graph not RDB.
But I think some ways may exist to fetch data without any NSSortDescriptor. I just want to fetch in the inserted order.

Its little annoying that all model objects must have sorting column, don't you think so?

Comment: In a pure RDB, you'd have to do the same (example: sqlite has rowids, but they change when the database is vacuumed)... Regardless, the notion of an "insertion order" is something that is quite specific to your particular business case and, thus, is not something that should be provided "for free" given that most entities have no need.

Comment: Umm... you're right, its my specific case. I've been working with database in years, so I'm feeling awkwardness for using CoreData for now... Anyway I'll keep trying, thanks again!

Comment: Following upon on @bbum's comments, what it sounds like you want to is simply add a property for date created (or whatever is an appropriate name for your context). Then sort on this date value when you fetch.

Comment: OMG!!!!!. So Im building a SwiftUI app and keep running into these weird error messages. Sorting by id should be a no no on the gd core data page on the apple website. 16 hours of destroying anything within arms reach and this ended up saving my apartment. Thank you sir for posting this invaluable information. DO NOT SORT BY ID is now pasted on my desktop.

Comment: @leeriesimpson Happy that this decade old (!!) comment is still helpful!!

Answer (score 3):

Use a sort descriptor with `self` as the sort key (instead of `id`). The underlying SQL will have `ORDER BY t0.Z_PK`.

Warning: as mentioned by vastopa below this is undocumented and crashes in iOS 10, and there is also a non-null probability that this breaks in a future version of iOS, so use at your own risk.

Comment: This solution will crash in iOS 10.3.1 (for anyone still supporting that version). Here is the resulting exception: `CoreDataSampleProject[4715:28570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath #self not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Person id=1>'` It's likely that support for self was not added till a later iOS version and since this behavior is undocumented, I'd suggest against using it since Apple can change this in a future version of iOS. So I'd agree with bbum and say that you should sort based on another CoreData attribute you've defined.

Comment: @vastopa Thanks for pointing out the incompatibility with previous versions, I did not try that. I can't remember now how I came up with this, I'll try to find a reference. I suspect that the support for this is here to stay but caution is indeed appropriate.