# Sorting entities in fetch request by id

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a model named `Store`. In this I have attributes such as `name, location, phone` and so on. I want to sort the stores on Id´s like you do in SQL, however is this possible? Normally the frameworks add an auto Id for you. If Core Data does that how do I get a hold of the value, and is it possible to sort on this value?
Do I need to add a field to the model and handle this myself, which I do not want.

I saw something about using a Date field and let it have a default value of "NOW", is this how you do it? In that case of do you add default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting by id (or primary key) is an unsupported scenario. Please see [CoreData: How to sort NSManagedObject by its primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120136/coredata-how-to-sort-nsmanagedobject-by-its-primary-key) for a similar, duplicate thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you like to have the id as a proxy for the created date. I recommend you add a property `timestamp` of type `NSDate` and initialize it to `[NSDate date]` when you create a new managed object instance. Then you simply sort by that.

```
newStore.timestamp = [NSDate date];
```

and

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
```

Incidentally this is the default implementation of the old Apple project templates.